# Can より be used in questions of comparison?

Tags: questions, particle-より

Reading through several learning resources, questions of comparison are always shown of the following type:

> XとYと　どちら・・・

and statements of comparison are always shown of the following type:

> Xより　Yのほう・・・

None of the resources I can find however specifically state that the latter type (using より) is or is not grammatical for questions. Eg

> ＊中国は　日本より　大きいですか。

Is this construction rare or outright unacceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Both constructions are correct but they are asking different questions.

中国と日本とどちらが大きいですか means "Which is bigger between China and Japan?"

中国は日本より大きいですか means "Is China bigger than Japan?"